# T-SQL, string injection, REPLACE(@myVariable, '''', '''''') approach? Once and for all

Tags: sql-injection, string

I see there are forums about this question, but everywhere, I fail to see the answer I am looking for.

I have a stored procedure which its purpose is to execute dynamic SQL statement.
It uses a cursor which makes it a single point where only a single REPLACE() is made.
Here is, simply, how at the end it goes.

Here is a sample of my approach:

```
DECLARE @myVariable VARCHAR(128) = 'something''; DELETE DATABASE '
DECLARE @mySQL VARCHAR(8000)
SELECT TOP 1 @mySQL = REPLACE('SELECT * FROM myTable t WHERE t.myColumn = ' + @myVariable + ''', '''', '''''')

EXEC (@mySQL)
// Result:
// SELECT * FROM myTable t WHERE t.myColumn = 'something''''; DELETE DATABASE'
```

There is no way I can find that this method can be bypassed.
Now I know there are a lot of answers to that questions and that it is already gone through.
But every answer to it I find FAILS to answer IN HOW WAY one would SUCCESSFULLY string inject ANYTHING through this. I know that parameterized expressions are a best practice but it IS NOT an answer to this.

I want a SINGLE example on how one could successfully string inject anything through that gate.

Comment: Welcome to the community. Why don't you just use prepared statements?..

Comment: I put all dynamic queries in a table before executing into a cursor, these are processed in a single query insert with REPLACE(, '''', ''''''), and I don't see any way of using the prepared statements in that matter.

Comment: I'm not sure but replacing I think it not the best idea because you can strip away something which ends up executing in the end...

Comment: I guess the structure has to be thought a better perspective to include prepared statements. You are right, running after inputs is a bad design to start with.